# R How do I unquote an input to table function so that it’s evaluated, not quoted

Tags: r, quote

I have made some fake data to illustrate my problem. I have a data frame with a bunch of columns. I have another data frame with a column containing a subset of column names from the first data frame. I want to use the table function to generate a count of the number of observations of the columns and store that in a data frame.

Here is my attempt:

#### Creating fake data

```
data=as.data.frame(cbind(
sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE),
sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE),
sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE),
sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE),
sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE),
sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE)))
```

#### Creating data with Needed Variable Names

```
variables=data.frame(Domains=c("V2","V5","V6"))
```

#### Attempt

```
counts=data.frame(table(noquote(gsub(" ", "",
     paste("data$",as.character(variables$Domains),collapse=",")))))
```

The counts object contains the following: "data$V2,data$V5,data$V6" with a frequency of 1 instead of my desired table. My actual use case is a bit more complex than this but this distills the problem I am making.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is your use case covered by doing `table(data[variables$Domains])` rather than trying to generate `table(data$V2, data$V5, data$V6)` programmatically? Usually there's ways in R to send an entire list or object as input instead of needing to do this kind of meta-programming.

Comment: Yes, that does work, thank you! I'll keep this technique in mind for the future, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
colSums(data[,variables$Domains])
#> V2 V5 V6 
#>  4  8  7
```

Comment: I'm looking for the cross-combinations so this isn't quite what I'm looking for, but the other comment contains the solution I need. Both show use of the concept I didn't know. I appreciate you taking the time to help.